# What is a common single-user database for Mac OSX development?

Tags: ios, database, macos

I am just starting to study and develop Mac OSX applications, and I'd like to design an app that uses a database.

I'm not opposed to something like MySQL, but I'm looking for something that can be single user and can be stored directly on the device so internet access is not required. I'd prefer not to resort to writing/reading from a file either.

The closest I've come to find is SQLite, which I am familiar with in Android development, but my question is: is that what most OSX developers use?

I am trying to pose this question in a way that is not opinion-driven, as I know there are countless DBMS out there. Is there one that leads the pack as far as being used with OSX?

Comment: CoreData as an object persistence layer over SQLite is quite common.  You'll also find a fair number of people using SQLite directly.

Comment: Does that hold true for iOS as well? (I would assume yes)

Comment: I think most people would use Core Data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Higher Abstractions:**

Core Data is available on iOS and OSX.

[Realm](http://realm.io) is a popular alternative to Core Data. Some of the features include:

- Fast
- Memory efficient
- Its safe and easy to use across multiple threads (core data can be tricky here).

Like Core Data it uses the Active Record pattern, where persistence methods are defined on the model objects themselves (unlike the DAO pattern, which uses a separate interface).

**Lower Abstractions:**

[FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) is a nice Objective-C API that sits over the pure C API to sqlite.

Comment: Is Core Data a good option to use if I ever wanted to migrate to a multi-user database in the long run?

Comment: Someone with more CoreData experience may disagree, but I think no, you'd be looking for an approach that gives you full control over the table structure at the same time as having an expressive OO model. For this I like FMDB with the DAO pattern, where the DAO translates to/from the relational DB. If you change the model and/or the table structure you can modify the DAO implementation to reflect this. (Here's an example of a DAO: https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon-Swift-Example/blob/master/PocketForecast/Dao/CityDao.swift )